# Presenting Storyboard ViewController Error Only for iOS 13

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to present a ViewController I created in storyboard programmatically in iOS 13 but it keeps crashing. The identifier is correct because works for iOS 12, just not 13. It crashes at where I instantiateViewController.

```
 @IBAction func addStock(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let searchVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchViewController") as! SearchViewController

    searchVC.delegate = self
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchVC)

    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show crash log please.

Comment: hey Matt, I added some pictures so show you what its like. I error was confusing to me